# Как удалить элементы из строки

Tags: php

Есть строка, в ней есть теги вида:

```
<td class="delite">текст</td>
```

Таких тегов много. Как удалить их вместе с тем что содержится внутри этих тегов?

Буду благодарен за помощь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для поиска с последующей модификацией строк используйте [**preg_replace()**](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-replace.php):

```
$string = '<td class="delite">текст</td>';

echo preg_replace('~<td class="delite">.+?</td>~i', '', $string);
```

Если открывающий и закрывающий теги находятся на разных строках, добавьте в шаблон модификатор *s*: `'~<td class="delite">.+?</td>~is'`